# Can I query a TSV file directly using Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, csv, apache-spark

Is it possible to query a TSV file directly using Spark SQL? To be clear, I'm talking about Spark SQL not Spark DataFrame. For example, we can query a CSV file directly using Spark SQL. Is there a way to specify the delimiter in a (Spark) SQL statement?

```
spark.sql("select * from csv.`/path/to/csv`")
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. Any sql query on the spark happens on the dataframe abstraction.

You need to first load the TSV data into a dataframe then you can query.

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter","\t").option("header", "true").csv("/path/to/csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempTable("tableName")
spark.sql("select * from tableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have a problem using createOrReplaceTempTable. Use createOrReplaceTempView**
And you cannot specify delimiter at spark.sql level queries.

Try this -

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter","\t").option("header", "true").csv("/path/to/csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tableName")
spark.sql("select * from tableName)
```